# Почему функция g_object_set выбрасывает исключение (vcruntime140.dll)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, gstreamer

```
#pragma comment(lib, "gstreamer-1.0.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "gobject-2.0.lib")


#include <iostream>
#include <gst/gst.h>


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    gst_init( &argc, &argv );

    GstElement *source = gst_element_factory_make("rtspsrc", "test_src");
    g_object_set(source, "location", "trololo");
    std::cout << "End";

}
```

После выполнения **g_object_set** выбрасывается такое исключение: **Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF87285193C (vcruntime140.dll) in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000008000.**
Почему?

Comment: Скорее всего потому, что функция `gst_element_factory_make` завершилась безуспешно и вернула null. Именно об этом вы и должны спрашивать: почему `gst_element_factory_make` завершилась безуспешно.

Comment: @AnT Она вернула не NULL...